# I cannot install my Belkin N firmware on my new Windows 7 computer

Tags: windows-7, router

I recently bought a new PC with Windows 7 installed, I already had a Belkin N wireless router on my home network (Belkin N wireless router F5D8236-4 v-3).

I can use the Internet when I am connected directly to my cable modem, but I have not been able to install the Belkin software onto my Windows 7 computer. When trying to download the software from the Belkin website, I save the file, but Windows 7 does not recogonize the file type.

Can I use this Belkin router with my new computer? Do I need to buy a new router?

Comment: What's the file extension? What did you try to download (name of the software)?

Comment: Thanks for the response, the file extension is .binf5d7234-4_ww_3.00.03

Comment: .bin the download file name from the belkin website is f5d7234-4_ww_3.00.03

Comment: You need to navigate to your router's setting and select the file. Read [here](http://en-us-support.belkin.com/app/answers/page/a_id/497) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

You say in the title that you are trying to install the router firmware on the computer.  You can't.  I am not repeating that you can't, I am telling you that the firmware you downloaded is not to be installed on the computer... it is to be installed on the router.  Firmware is the mini-OS that is running on the router.  When you connect to the router's admin panel, you are interacting with that firmware.  If you downloaded something that was called Firmware, then it was to replace what is on your router.  It is not a program you run on your computer

Comment: I see, then I shouldn't have downloaded that. I tried to use the installation cd that came with the router, however, it supports windows 2000, XP and Vista. I can't get it to install on windows 7. That's why I tried the Belkin website. I must have downloeded the wrong file.

Answer (score 2):

> I can use the Internet when I am connected directly to my cable modem, but I have not been able to install the Belkin software onto my Windows 7 computer.

Since it's router software, it shouldn't install on a PC. It should install on a router.

> When trying to download the software from the Belkin website, I save the file, but Windows 7 does not recogonize the file type.

Again, it's router software. Windows 7 shouldn't recognize it. Windows 7 is not a router.

> Can I use this Belkin router with my new computer?

Sure. Just stop trying to install its software on your computer. Just use it.

> Do I need to buy a new router?

No.

No software needs to be installed on your computer. Your computer doesn't care what router it's using and your router doesn't care what computer is using it. Your computer and your router each do their own job with their own software.

The router firmware is only provided if you want to re-install or upgrade the router firmware. There is no reason you would normally need to do that.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses eveyone, I see that I have downloaded a file for the router which I do not need, my only issue now is to figure out how to get the Belkin software CD installed on my computer. It appears it's was issued prior to windows 7

Comment: If you look at the stroked out part of my answer, you shouldn't need any software in your PC. If you can't install the program anyway, try  to properties -> compatability and select "Windows XP Service Pack 2" from the dropdown menu and then running it.

Answer (score 1):

First, unless your Belkin router isn't working to your satisfaction, there's probably no real need to install new firmware for the router.

That said, a ".bin" extension is fine. It doesn't matter if Windows doesn't recognize that file type (this is actually the typical case); you can still transfer it over to your router, and it will know what to do with it (assuming your firmware file isn't corrupt or something).

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The router will work fine without the software.</strike>

The software is generally just a way for the user to easily access the router's settings, although in most cases this can also be accessed using your external IP address locally in a browser.

edit: or use 192.168.2.1.

About the software you download- are you sure it's for Windows and not for Linux or OSX? Either way, it's not really needed.

edit 2: in regards to your comment:

You need to navigate to your router's setting and select the file. Read [here](http://en-us-support.belkin.com/app/answers/page/a_id/497) for more info.

I miss-read your question the first time.

Comment: Hi Mathew, I called it "firmware" because that's how it is listed on the Belkin website. I downloaded the version for Windows 7 home premium 64 bit. I am not very ecxperienced with software issues, so my terminology may be incorrect. On my old computer, which had XP, I had no issues using the Belkin router, when I bought the new computer, it just does no recognize the router, so I am connected directly to the modem at present. When I ran the diagnostics in windows, it could not find the router, so I don't know how I can configure it without having a way to find it first.

Comment: If you're connected using an ethernet cable it should be working without any further set-up required, did you try entering http://192.168.2.1 in your browser? That should bring you to the router's configuration page where you can install the new firmware.

Also take a look at the link I posted in my last answer if you haven't already- that may help you.

Comment: Mathew, thanks again, I had incorrectly downloaded the firmware file. Unfortunately, my computer does not recognize the router at all, I tried to install the sfotware that came with the router, but it will not. The CD says it's for Windows 2000, XP and Vista. This is why I went to the Belkin website. I am not using the router at all right now, I can only connect by plugging directly to the modem. I did try entering 192.168.2.1 in the browser when the router was connected, but nothing came up.

Comment: @BrianLook: Is the router at factory default settings? If so, connect the computer to one of the router's LAN ports. Reboot the computer, and then point a browser at the router's default IP address. It's probably either `192.168.0.1`, `192.168.1.1`, or `192.168.2.1`. If the router is not at factory defaults, you'll probably want to reset it first.